# Elasticsearch update document with matching id

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to update the document in elasticsearch which matches the id field. If the `formData.id` matches any of the documents in elasticsearch, I want it's `mobile_number` and `primary_email_id` to be updated. I also want to insert a new field `website` to the matching result. For this, I tried the following query:

```
function updateForm(formData) {
var deferred = Q.defer();
client.update({
    index: 'collections',
    type: 'automobiles',
    id: '8s5WEbYZ6NUAliwOBf',
     body: {
            query: {
                must: { 
                  match :  {
                      id: formData.id
                    } 
                },
            },
            doc: {
                'mobile_number' : formData.phone,
                'primary_email_id': formData.email,
                'website' : formData.website
            }

    }
},function (error, response) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }else {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }

  }); 
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

This gives me the following error:

`Error: [action_request_validation_exception] Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;`

I already have a doc field in my query. What modifications should I make to perform such an update? Is there any other better way for such an operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified my query and it's working now. `id` is the only unique field for each of the document in `collections`. So, I had to include that as well in `doc`. The updated function:

```
function putForm(formData) {
console.log(formData);
var deferred = Q.defer();
client.update({
    index: 'collections',
    type: 'automobile',
    id: '8s5WEbYZ6NUAliwOBf',
    body: {
        doc: {
            'id' : formData.id,
            'mobile_number' : formData.mobile_number,
            'primary_email_id': formData.primary_email_id,
            'website' : formData.website,

          }
        }
},function (error, response) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }else {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }

  }); 
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here, `id` outside the body field is id of `collections` while `formData.id` refers to individual documents present in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the JS API but I think it should look this way:

```
function updateForm(formData) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  client.update(
    {
      index: 'collections',
      type: 'automobiles',
      id: formData.id,
      body: {
        doc: {
          'mobile_number' : formData.phone,
          'primary_email_id': formData.email,
          'website' : formData.website
        }
      }
    },  
    function (error, response) {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(response);
     }
    }
  ); 
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Based on: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-update

Comment: This returns `{ Error: [document_missing_exception] [hospitals][6182251538764430848]: document missing, with { index_uuid="FODIXynqSkOCyZg5PGfvtQ" & shard="3" & index="collections" }`